# Browserify onClick not called but alert() ok

Tags: javascript, browserify

I’m having problems with browserify.  In short, my onclick function is not being called with my bundle.js but it will fire if I include my main.js as a script tag in index.html.  I have saved and run

browserify main.js > bundle.js

in the terminal with no results.  Even stranger, when I throw an alert function in my main.js and run browserify again the alert if successfully called from bundle.js

Interestingly, my require() function is working fine in the browser so bundle.js is doing something. My code is below

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a id="toolsPage" onclick="ToolsPage(this)"href="#">Tools</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var EthUtil = require("ethereumjs-util");


alert("yo1");

var hexToBytes = function(hex) {
  for (var bytes = [], c = 0; c < hex.length; c+=2)
  bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
  return bytes;
}

var privateKeyToAddress = function(privateKey) {
  return `0x${EthUtil.privateToAddress(hexToBytes(privateKey)).toString('hex')}`
}

alert(privateKeyToAddress("ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad"));


function ToolsPage (id) {

  alert("tools");

}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "new",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babelify": "^8.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.1.0",
    "ethereumjs-util": "^5.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.30"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

The ToolsPage function is not being called. What about browserify is disabling this function?

Comment: hope that's not your real private key

Comment: ha no just sha256 of abc